# How to use unbound descriptor range properly in descriptor tables

Tags: vulkan, hlsl, directx12, directx

I am trying to use 2 "D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE" in a root descriptor table,defined as follows:

```
//1st range 
D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE materialtablerange = {};
materialtablerange.OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = 0;
materialtablerange.NumDescriptors = 1;
materialtablerange.RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE::D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
materialtablerange.RegisterSpace = 0;
materialtablerange.BaseShaderRegister = 1;
D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE* tableranges = new D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE[2];
//2nd range
D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE texturesrvrange = {};
texturesrvrange.RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE::D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
texturesrvrange.BaseShaderRegister = 0;
texturesrvrange.RegisterSpace = 0;
texturesrvrange.NumDescriptors = -1;
texturesrvrange.OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = 2;
```

So we have 1st range which specifies 1 srv and 2nd range which defines an unbound srv array.
Unfortunately this does not seems to work as when I try to serialize the rootsignature via "D3D12SerializeRootSignature".I get "E_INVALIDARG" return code and error msg(from blob as following:
"Shader register range of type SRV (root parameter [1], visibility PIXEL, descriptor table slot [1]) overlaps with another shader register range (root parameter[1], visibility PIXEL, descriptor table slot [0])."
This issue seems to go away if I set NumDescriptors in 2nd range as 1.So I wanted to understand why these 2 ranges are raising an overlap error message in rootsignature Serialize and how to set it up properly,if possible?